# asyncio tasks using aiohttp.ClientSession

Tags: python, aiohttp, python-asyncio

I'm using python 3.7 and trying to make a crawler that can go multiple domains asynchronously. I'm using for this asyncio and aiohttp but i'm experiencing problems with the aiohttp.ClientSession. This is my reduced code:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        print(await response.text())

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        cwlist = [loop.create_task(fetch(session, url)) for url in ['http://python.org', 'http://google.com']]
        asyncio.gather(*cwlist)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The thrown exception is this:

> _GatheringFuture exception was never retrieved
>   future: <_GatheringFuture finished exception=RuntimeError('Session is closed')>

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `await` the `asyncio.gather` result:

```
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        cwlist = [loop.create_task(fetch(session, url)) for url in ['http://python.org', 'http://google.com']]
        await asyncio.gather(*cwlist)
```

If you ever have an `async with` containing no `await` expressions you should be fairly suspicious.